# Ubuntu Error Invalid command 'ServerAdmin', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Tags: laravel, ubuntu

I am trying to upload my laravel project on aws by installing ubuntu. I pretty much already installed everything I have to but after writing .conf inside the sites-available, and reloading the apache2.service. There is an error indicating that the ServerAdmin is misspelled.

domain.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    SeverAdmin ...@gmail.com
    ServerName domain.com
    SeverAlias www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain/public
    
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/domain>
        Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
    Options Indexes Multiviews FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I literally see `Sever` instead of `Server`

Comment: I also realised now that you have `SeverAlias` too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about that everyone! That was a simple spelling mistake